# Stock App Distributed Backend Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, distributed, stock

## General Information

**I'm building a stock app as a side project and this is the current architecture I'm using:**

- React Frontend with **@microsoft/signalr** socket library
- ASP.NET Core Backend with **SignalR Hub** to handle client sockets
- Polygon.io REST API as a Financial Data Source
- Redis to store stock quotes so multiple API Nodes can query the data

**Here is a sample of the preliminary architecture I came up with:**

[image]

**Some Challenges**

- Stock quotes need to be updated every second/every few seconds for good UX
- Multiple clients share subscriptions to the same stocks
- Just on NYSE there's `n=11,750` possible stocks to subscribe to

## The current update mechanism

### Client 1

- **Client #1** connects to **API Node #1**
- **Client #1** subscribes to `$AAPL`, `$TSLA`
- **API Node #1** starts a timer, every 2 seconds it polls Redis and looks up `AAPL` and `TSLA` keys to see if values exist, if values are missing it polls Polygon for the missing quotes, then stores them in Redis and caches the keys for 3 seconds.
- The mix of cached/new data is returned to **Client #1**

### Client 2

- **Client #2** connects to **API Node #2**
- **Client #2** subscribes to `$AAPL`, `$TSLA`, `$GOOG`, `$AMZN`
- It shares the `$AAPL` and `$TSLA` subscriptions with **Client #1**
- **API Node #2** starts a timer, every 2 seconds it polls **Redis** and looks up `AAPL`,`TSLA`,`GOOG`,`AMZN` keys to see if values exist, if values are missing it polls Polygon for the missing quotes, then stores them in Redis and caches the keys for 3 seconds.
- The mix of cached/new data is returned to **Client #2**

## The problem

**Client #1** and **Client #2** share subscriptions and sometimes they will try to update the same keys in Redis and poll Polygon for the same stocks. What would be the most efficient way for API Nodes to update stocks?

## Solutions for efficient scaling

Should I create a central worker that queries Polygon.io and updates **ALL** aggregated stock subscriptions in Redis instead and API nodes only poll from Redis cache?